# How to handle keyboard event for native QWidget?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a native widget (for custom 3d rendering) inside main application. And I want to handle native keyboard events, like `WM_KEYDOWN`, `WM_KEYUP` or `WM_CHAR`.

Next code is used for creation:

```
NativeWidget::NativeWidget( QWidget *parent )
    : QWidget(parent)
{
    setWindowFlags( windowFlags() | Qt::FramelessWindowHint );
    // Focus policy is WheelFocus
    setAttribute( Qt::WA_OpaquePaintEvent, true );
    setAttribute( Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground, true );
    setAttribute( Qt::WA_PaintOnScreen, true );
    setAttribute( Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true );
    setAttribute( Qt::WA_NativeWindow, true );
}
```

And next code is used to handle native events:

```
bool NativeWidget::nativeEvent( const QByteArray& eventType, void* msg, long* result )
{
    MSG *message = static_cast<MSG *>( msg );

    switch ( message->message )
    {
    case WM_LBUTTONDBLCLK:
    case WM_RBUTTONDBLCLK:
    case WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
    // ...Some debug stuff...
    case WM_NCPAINT:
    case WM_MOUSELEAVE:
        break;

    case WM_CHAR:
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
    case WM_KEYUP:
        // OMG! I couldn't get there... :(
        break;

    default:
        qDebug() << message->message;
        break;
    }

    return QWidget::nativeEvent( eventType, message, result );
}
```

I receive mouse events here, but no keyboard events are passed. How to handle them on native level?

Overriding `keyPressEvent` or `keyReleaseEvent` is working OK, but I need a handler for native events.

In Qt4 there was a `QWidget::winEvent` method, which works fine. But in Qt5 it was replaced with `QWidget::nativeEvent` - and I have problems with it.

UPDATE: [Bugreport](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-42183) with minimal sample (cmake-based)

Comment: You need low level keyboard hook, no? If so, I can get you example which works succesfully on XP and 7 without dll

Comment: I don't need hooks, I just want to handle native keyboard events, as I did in Qt4 with overriding `QWidget::winEvent` method.

Comment: Sorry, you really don't need hook. Moreover your code should works, I run this code and get results, so answer should be very interesting.

Comment: did you take a look at QEvent?

Comment: I also think that it should work. Don't you have another input control which receives events at this moment?

Comment: @gekannt what exact should i look in `QEvent`?

Comment: @Chernobyl what results?

Comment: @Ezee no I don't have another input controls. I noted that overriding `keyPressEvent` is working OK. But I need a handling on native level (it's requirements of our game engine).

Comment: I run your NativeWidget(not whole project, just all widget) in my computer and as I said it works, I can catch key up and dow messages. But I use qt5.2.0 and I'm not so experienced to do some conclusions. Unfortunately.

Comment: I created a bugreport.

Comment: @DmitrySazonov, voted up your bug report, as this bug still not fixed in Qt 5.12. Just wanted to updated here in case someone going through this.

Comment: @GiladReich thanks, but issue still have low priority. Don't know, is it possible to do something.